# How do I get rid of this black screen when trying to install ubuntu on m1 mac using virtual machine?

Tags: graphics, 22.04, virtualization, mac, arm

I've tried changing my cores and RAM settings as well, but to no avail. I looked for a similar issue online, but couldn't find one. I'm currently using 4 cores with 4GB RAM and 30GB disk space.

I'm using UMT as the virtualization application.

I'm getting this after clicking on *Install Ubuntu 22.04*.

[image: Screenshot of what I'm getting after clicking on "Install Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS"]

Comment: What virtualisation platform are you using? If VirtualBox, I suspect this is due to the lack of GPU passthrough or acceleration. Typically a black window like this is because there's problem rendering a GL context. I believe only Parallels on the M1 mac is able to do GPU accelerated guest desktop.

Comment: Right now i'm using UMT. In the examples that I've seen M1 Macs worked completely normally on there.

Comment: Interesting, UMT uses QEMU under the hood I believe.

Comment: It worked flawlessly! Thank you very much for your help.